# How can i write power procedure in sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
create prozedure hochdrei
(declare @ x int)
declare @x int
begin
set @x = 3
print power(@x, 3)
return x
end
```

Comment: microsoft sql server management

Comment: Power is already a function in SQL Server, do you really need to implement it as an SP?

Comment: yes, i need this , it is for Uni

Comment: if it's a procedure, then do `select power(@x, 3)` to return the value

Comment: Also: its `procedure` not `prozedure`

Comment: can i write print(select power(@x, 3) ?

Comment: @ЛераКулакова don't use print to return values, it displays the results on another output channel which is usually used to debug or ad-hoc commentaries. Either use SELECT or an OUTPUT parameter.

Comment: No: `print` can process simple values (varchar, int etc) but not query result sets.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE hochdrei
    @x INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT power(@x, 3)
END
```

Note that, in the above SP, you will pass the X value as an input parameter to the Stored Procedure.

You can call the Stored Procedure like this.

```
EXEC hochdrei 2
```

> Result: 8

If you don't want to pass the X as a parameter then you will use below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE hochdrei        
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @x INT=2
    SELECT power(@x, 3)
END
```

Call the SP as;

```
EXEC hochdrei
```

> Result: 8

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Exponentiation
    @Base FLOAT,
    @Exponent FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT POWER(@Base, @Exponent) AS Power
END
```

Executions example:

```
EXEC Exponentiation -- Result: 4096
    @Base = 4,
    @Exponent = 6

EXEC Exponentiation 10, 4 -- Result: 10000

EXEC Exponentiation 1000, -0.5 -- Result: 0.0316227766016838 (1 / √1000)
```